# Invoking a function calculation in C through a pointer defined in a structure, when function is written in assembly code

Tags: c, pointers

I have a piece of code I am trying to understand how it works. SGENT_1_calc is a signal generator function, written as assembly code elsewhere. When the calculation is invoked in C,  sgen.calc(&sgen),  requires its own structure address as argument. Why ?
THANKS IN ADVANCE FOR YOUR HELP !

```c
typedef struct {   
    unsigned int freq;
    unsigned int step_max;
    unsigned int alpha;
    int gain;
    int offset;
    int out;
    void (*calc)(void *);
    }SGENT_1;

#define SGENT_1_DEFAULTS    { 5369,
    1000,
    0,
    0x7fff,
    0,
    0,
    (void (*)(void *))SGENT_1_calc}    // pointer casted here ???


    void SGENT_1_calc(void *);  //SGENT1_calc is a signal generator function


    SGENT_1 sgen = SGENT_1_DEFAULTS; // this is an instance 

    sgen.calc(&sgen);  //don't understand how the calculation is invoked, 
                       // why it has &sgen as an argument ???
```

Comment: please reformat the code properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sgen.calc` is a pointer to a function accepting one argument of type `void *` and returning nothing.  It is irrelevant how the machine code of the pointed-to function was produced.  In any event, the *value* of `sgen.calc` carries no information about the variable in which that value is stored, so if `sgen` contains the data to be submitted to the function, then the fact that its `calc` member points to that function doesn't provide any way around passing (a pointer to) that `struct`.

Given no other information about the function pointed to by `sgen.calc`, a pointer to `sgen` is as good an argument for it as any other object pointer.  There is nothing inherently special about choosing that particular argument over any other.

In fact, however, it is reasonable to suppose that the function assumes its argument to point to a data structure with a particular layout.  The C code implies that type `SGENT_1` is consistent with that layout.  It is impossible to determine from the code presented whether the function uses the `calc` member of that `struct`, but its placement as the last member is consistent with it not doing so.  In that case, it may be included in the C `struct` simply for organizational purposes.

Comment: You are correct in your assumption: SGENT_1 doesn't use the calc member but it does use all other members in the structure, in that order too. It then may make sense to use &sgen as argument. I just don't know how the argument &sgen from C is used in the assembly code of SGENT_1 so that it can access the members of the structure. In any case, the code only executes correctly with &sgen as argument. Thanks for your help !